# How do I navigate to another page within my Elm application?

Tags: elm

**How do I navigate to another page within my Elm application?**

Specifically, I am trying to navigate from the *Home* page to the *Contributor* page.

The *Contributor* page is located under my *Domain* folder.

The file structure is below:

```
- Home.elm
- Domain
  - Contributor.elm
```

I thought I could do something like this:

```
a [href "Domain/Contributor.elm"] [text "click me!"]
```

or this:

```
a [href "Domain/Contributor.html"] [text "click me!"]
```

However, neither of these paths work.

Note: 
The app that I'm working on is NOT a SPA.

Comment: How are you building and running the application? Is this just using `elm-reactor`? If it is not a SPA, you'll need some server application or static html pages to house each Elm component

Comment: I'm using Elm-Live. Is there any guidance on doing this for my case? Here's the repo: https://github.com/Lambda-Cartel/Nikeza

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `elm-live`, which is a development server. It targets a single Elm source file as its entry point, so unless your Elm code is built as a single page application, you won't be able to do any navigation to another file (though there is nothing wrong with hard-coding `href` links that link elsewhere).

elm-live is also only for development. You wouldn't want to run it on a production server.

If you are trying to avoid a SPA and would rather have each Elm file represent the complete functionality for a single page, perhaps you could go with the default functionality of `elm make`, which generates an HTML file that contains inline javascript compiled from Elm code. This is, in essence, what drives the [elm-lang.org](http://elm-lang.org) website. If you look at the source code, you'll see the html generated by the default `elm make` command, compiled against each Elm file "page" of the application.

On the other hand, if you are trying to build a SPA, @Bill's answer is a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks Chad. I executed a make for that specific file. I can now navigate to the file. However, the page is blank (which is another problem).

Comment: The Contributor.elm file will need a `main` function that wires up the program if you want to run it as a standalone page.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe you can do the sort of navigation you are trying to do within an Elm app without building a SPA. You are attempting to use the HTML href attribute to navigate. That attribute needs to be a real URL. Without using something like the Elm navigation package, you wont's have support for multiple routes.

Simple navigation in Elm is fairly straightforward. I wrote a [blog post on this subject](https://becoming-functional.com/single-page-web-apps-in-elm-535145569bed).

Also, here is the [github repo that demonstrates the work](https://github.com/billperegoy/elm-spa) in this post.